# MATLAB avoid multiline strings

Tags: string, matlab, struct, char, multiline

I've a struct array in which I store chapters title and other info after an OCR, at the end there's a GUI for manual adjustment in case of ocr failing.

All works fine but after an editing or if I reopen the GUI later from the command windows the strings are messed up, short strings have e blank space after every char, for example:

'first chapter' becomes 'f i r s t  c h a p t e r'

while longer strings skip a row every character

'THIS IS AN EXAMPLE' becomes 'TE HX IA SM  IP SL AE N'

I thought it was due to multiline strings but converting in a single line doesn't changed the results.

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: There is probably a bug somewhere in your code

Comment: 1) What release?
2) Does the numel of the string change?
3) It kind of sounds like you're saving it and loading it but with a different format. If you're saving it as a 2 byte character but reading it as a 1 byte character that might explain the inserted character. Call double() on the string and tell us the ascii value of the inserted character.
4) You probably have a bug.